# Show items (checkboxes, radiobuttons etc...) by case (if...else...etc...)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a little game in C#.
The program asks the user for a any number.
The user then presses "GO" (button1) and the program checks whether the number is an even number or not. (x % 2 == 0)

I'm trying to get the program to show 4 checkboxes/radio buttons out of total of 8 depending on each case.
For example:

- If the number is an EVEN NUMBER: The program will show options 2,5,3,6.
- If the number is an ODD NUMBER: The program will show options 1,4,7,8.

(Options 1-8 were already included in the design.)

I need help with the `if (x % 2 == 0)` part. What do I write in it to make the checkboxes/radiobuttons appear or disappear?

By the way, is there a way to ask the user for a number without him having to click "GO"?
Like, use ENTER instead. If yes, what event is that?
Also, is there a way to limit the textbox to INT only?

I know it's asking you to do the job, but I have tried, and I'm still a real beginner, therefore I think my way of learning is by actually experiencing it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Visible` property of the `CheckBox` (inherited from `Control`) will aid you in making the needed controls visible when you wish them to be. Your if would look something like,

```
if (num % 2 == 0) 
{
    box1.Visible = false;
    box2.Visible = true;
    // ...
}
else
{
    box1.Visible = true;
    box2.Visible = false;
    // ...
}
```

However, this can be optimized a bit by using the condition to set the visibility of all the `CheckBox`s at the same time instead of coding two conditionals - something like:

```
box1.Visible = !(num % 2 == 0);
box2.Visible = (num % 2 == 0);
// ...
```

As for on pressing enter, check the `OnKeyDown` event for you control, you can do this through the designer. Your event method would look like:

```
private void myControl_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Handle enter key pressed here
    }
}
```

This should help you with your problems.

**ADDITIONAL RESPONSE**

```
List<CheckBox> boxes = new List<CheckBox>();
// Add all boxes and do other stuff, disable all

foreach (CheckBox box in boxes)
{
    box.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way, is there a way to hide all of the boxes altogether?  Instead of writing `box1.Visible=false;box2.Visible=false` for all of them?

Comment: Toss them in an generic list, (`List<CheckBox> boxes`) and use a `foreach` loop. I'll add a snippet to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to limit the textbox to `int`, you could override `OnKeyPressed`. As for your checkboxes, you could use the `Visible` or `Checked` properties.